# Can't install nim inside of env

Tags: python, installation, pip

I'm attempting to install nim into a folder where I'm experimenting using virtual environment, but I can't seem to install nim using pip install nim. Any ideas why, I've included the error message. Thank you! :)

```
 Collecting nim
      Using cached nim-0.1.0.tar.gz (11 kB)
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/jq/_5zq1xh91hgcj49vb9lh689h0000gn/T/pip-install-c6r0gd5_/nim/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/jq/_5zq1xh91hgcj49vb9lh689h0000gn/T/pip-install-c6r0gd5_/nim/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/jq/_5zq1xh91hgcj49vb9lh689h0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-lhsvapoi
             cwd: /private/var/folders/jq/_5zq1xh91hgcj49vb9lh689h0000gn/T/pip-install-c6r0gd5_/nim/
        Complete output (11 lines):
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "/private/var/folders/jq/_5zq1xh91hgcj49vb9lh689h0000gn/T/pip-install-c6r0gd5_/nim/setup.py", line 171, in <module>
            pkg_data = _package_data(__file__.replace('setup.py', '__init__.py'))
          File "/private/var/folders/jq/_5zq1xh91hgcj49vb9lh689h0000gn/T/pip-install-c6r0gd5_/nim/setup.py", line 150, in _package_data
            data = literal_eval(u''.join(lines))
          File "/private/var/folders/jq/_5zq1xh91hgcj49vb9lh689h0000gn/T/pip-install-c6r0gd5_/nim/setup.py", line 122, in literal_eval
            return _convert(node_or_string)
          File "/private/var/folders/jq/_5zq1xh91hgcj49vb9lh689h0000gn/T/pip-install-c6r0gd5_/nim/setup.py", line 69, in _convert
            if isinstance(node, (Str, Bytes)):
        NameError: name 'Str' is not defined
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: there seems to be an error in some code somewhere. I am unsure whether it is the pip source code or from the package, but try reinstalling pip and to its latest version.

Comment: There is a bug in `setup.py`, you'll have to report that to the package developer. Though from the [pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/nim/), that package does not seem to be active or maintained anymore. There are no other releases, and the homepage and Bitbucket repo links are both dead. I suggest looking for other python-to-nim packages.

Comment: Or you could fork the project, fix the `setup.py` file, and install.